# Rails app is using SSL even though I don't want it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.napcsweb.com/blog/2013/07/21/rails_ssl_simple_wa/) "Rails with SSL in Development The Simple Way" and successfully set up SSL for a Rails app. Now I created a second Rails app and it is trying to use SSL even though I didn't configure it to.

I am wondering why this is happening and what I can do to stop it.

I did manage to get the second app working by following the steps in the tutorial, but I didn't intend to make it use SSL. Before doing that, it was throwing errors about `invalid HTTP format, parsing fails` and my browser said `SSL connection error - ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. I even made sure that `config.force_ssl` was set to `false` in in `application.rb`

The command to start the thin SSL server is `thin start --ssl  --ssl-key-file server.key --ssl-cert-file server.crt`
 which is slightly different than the deprecated command in the tutorial.

I'm on Linux Mint by the way.

Comment: Have you tried starting the server with just "thin start"?

Comment: @gernberg very good, thank you. This works when `force_ssl=false`, and after trying this `rails server` appears to work again. Do you have any idea what the cause of this was?